# What does "is seen to be" mean?

Tags: expressions, academia, research

I am writing an academic article and to give conservative opinion, I am thinking to use the following statement:

> XXX is seen to give worse results and therefore excluded in our report.

I am writing to confirm this surely give a "conservative sentiment" and does not lead to any misleadings or inappropriate in writing research papers. Thank you!

Comment: @Jim Thank you. I have changed the question.

Comment: What you are asking now seems to be primarily opinion based:  *Does this mislead or is it inappropriate in research papers?*  But in my opinion, throwing out data that does not fit your model ***is*** misleading.

Comment: XXX may not be data.

Comment: @Xanne -  Agree. It is the *results* of the XXX algorithm/approach/process that don’t look good.

Comment: Whatever else, “is seen to be” doesn't match "is seen to give" unless you want to stretch it out into "is seen to be giving…" If you did that, how would it not stretch the point too far? 

If you're not clear about the meaning, please don't use the phrase.

Comment: The problem is with the word "worse." This is the subjective element that makes the whole sentence uncertain. Is it "worse" because the test produced results outside of the range of values you were a priori hoping for?  Or is the variance in the data using XXX much greater, and therefore, by "worse" you intend to mean the method has less precision, e.g. wider confidence intervals? Because the question is about how to best make a conservative statement, the most conservative route sticks to facts and eliminates subjective adjectives such as "better" or "worse."

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear from your sentence that this is intended to be a conservative estimate; don't use this phrasing.

"Seen to be" carries an implication of some unspecified "agent" having made a judgment/observation.

> XXX is seen to give worse results

vaguely implies something like:

> (someone: the scientific community? unspecified experts? you?) have the opinion/observed that XXX gives worse results.

It's a colloquial phrase that shows up quite often, but I would advise avoiding it completely. It has the same issue as other phrasing like "people are saying" or "people agree that", etc; if someone reputable has dismissed a certain finding, or there are papers critiquing an approach, or there are observations that a method is suboptimal, *cite those findings instead*. If you're meaning that you've observed it yourself, *say that*.

What you probably actually mean to say is:

> XXX gives worse results

so just say that, no need to add excess words that imply consensus without providing any support. You're arguing it deserves being omitted from your analysis, so you better have a pretty good reason to exclude it, so say that reason:

> XXX performed poorly compared to YYY and ZZZ, and therefore is excluded from our report.

There is no need to bother being conservative, just to make your criteria clear.

Alternatively, you may have actually *used XXX* and found worse results. **If so, say it.** Your proposed wording does not indicate that *you* are the one that found worse performance/whatever with XXX.

Comment: I think "is seen to give" specifically indicates "has been observed to give" (i.e. "It has been observed that XXXX gives worse results") - though as you mention, it's vague and doesn't indicate who has made such observations.

Comment: @V2Blast Agreed; I've made some edits to clarify/emphasize that the problem is that it is vague: it's not clear who is doing the observations or what the conclusion is based on. When I see this in speaking or writing it looks like the speaker/author is trying to hide something behind unspecified authority.